# How to sort an array of dictionary in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swift4

This is my NSObject class

```
class CustomDate: NSObject {
    var quarter: Int!
    var day: String!
    var month: String!
    var db: String!
    var long: String!
    var unix: Int!

    init(quarter: Int, day: String, month: String, db: String, long: String, unix: Int) {
        super.init()

        self.quarter = quarter
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.db = db
        self.long = long
        self.unix = unix
    }
}
```

The variable I created to store CustomDate

```
var dates = [CustomDate]()
```

I am getting the data from json in a dictionary in 6 key value pairs what I want is as you can see the photo below is printing the date and month. But I need to sort json data in ascending order(or descending order). How can I do that here is my code. I am using alamofire to getting the data and I create a NSObject class to store data

```
func apiData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.lrs.org/random-date-generator?lim_quarters=40&source=api-docs", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let data = json["data"] as? [String: Any] else { return }

            for (_, value) in data {
                let dateValue = value as! [String: Any]
                let date = CustomDate(quarter: dateValue["quarter"] as! Int,
                                      day: dateValue["day"] as! String,
                                      month: dateValue["month"] as! String,
                                      db: dateValue["db"] as! String,
                                      long: dateValue["long"] as! String,
                                      unix: dateValue["unix"] as! Int)

                self.dates.append(date)
            }
            print(self.dates)
            break
        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Photo for example

[image]

Comment: which value you need to sort?

Comment: months value i need to sort

Comment: then in your custom class used sort function to sort in month

Comment: How can i do that sir ?

Comment: here is your code
let newArr = dates.sorted(by: { (objModel, objModel1) -> Bool in
                return (Int(objModel. month ?? "0") ?? 0) < (Int(objModel1. month ?? "0") ?? 0)
            })

Comment: would you post this as an answer in more details

Comment: Unrelated but **never ever** declare properties in a class as IUO which are initialized with non-optional values. Remove the exclamation marks.

Comment: Is your `month` property a `String`? Why would you sort on the basis of a `String`? It would make more sense if that's an `Int`.

Comment: yes sir months property is string

Comment: @vadian.... i don't understand sir

Comment: Declare the properties as non-optional (without exclamation marks). The code will compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare strings in numeric order either use `localizedStandardCompare` which sorts like in Finder

```
dates.sort(by: {$0.month.localizedStandardCompare($1.month) == .orderedAscending})
```

or `compare` with option `numeric`

```
dates.sort(by: {$0.month.compare($1.month, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending})
```

---

The best solution might be to declare `month` as `Int`.

Comment: if you compare string output is not desired because it compare ASCII value

Comment: @chiragshah It **is** *desired*, believe me. In ASCII `"10"` is less than `"2"`

Comment: @vadian but if i have "1","12","2" values then sorted like "1" , "12" and "2" not like it has too.

Comment: @chiragshah I think the OP wants the order `"1", "2", "12"`

Comment: self.dates.sort(by: {$0.day.localizedStandardCompare($1.day) == .orderedAscending}) i used this method for day but not working

Comment: @vadian for this dates.sort(by: {$0.month.compare($1.month, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending}) need to upvote

Comment: It **does** sort the days in numeric order but in the JSON `day` doesn't seem to be *day of month*

Comment: i am very confused... now app is sorting the day but not the month

Comment: In the action of the segmented control you have to reorder the array by the appropriate property.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your custom array by this. The **sort** is one of the **High order** function which used to sort custom array.

```
func apiData() {

    Alamofire.request("https://api.lrs.org/random-date-generator?lim_quarters=40&source=api-docs", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let data = json["data"] as? [String: Any] else { return }

            for (_, value) in data {
                let dateValue = value as! [String: Any]
                let date = CustomDate(quarter: dateValue["quarter"] as! Int,
                                      day: dateValue["day"] as! String,
                                      month: dateValue["month"] as! String,
                                      db: dateValue["db"] as! String,
                                      long: dateValue["long"] as! String,
                                      unix: dateValue["unix"] as! Int)

                self.dates.append(date)
            }
            print("unsorted array \(self.dates.map({$0.month})))")
            self.dates = self.dates.sorted(by: { (objModel, objModel1) -> Bool in return
                (Int(objModel.month ?? "0") ?? 0) < (Int(objModel1.month ?? "0") ?? 0)
            })
            print("sorted array \(self.dates.map({$0.month}))")
            break
        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting zero values in this.... I put this code in viewdidLoad method

Comment: did you try this after print(self.dates) statement ?

Comment: yes it showing the error  Definition conflicts with previous value

Comment: wait let me try here

Comment: @viper it's completely working fine here. I used same thing let me put screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173142/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-viper).